# Dynamically creating a series of oscillators that play with keyup/down

Tags: javascript, dom, web-audio-api

The problem is this:
In the following example, http://jsfiddle.net/GmgGY/2/

when you click on the orange button it creates a new div. When you click on this div it plays an oscillator. If you push a key on the keyboard (keydown) it plays it as well. It then stops playing it when the keyboard character is lifted (keyup). This is good and what I want.

However, when you click the orange button multiple times and create multiple synths. When you push a key on the keyboard all of them play (which is what I want) but only the last created one seems to respond to the keyup event.I want all of them to respond to the keyup event.Not just the last one.

I am not sure how to fix this.

Each dynamically created div has a unique ID but also a class that is universal to all of them. I thought there might be a way to select the class (  synth.class) and launch a universal oscillator.disconnect() on keyup ???

Another thing I'm thinking is my problem might need some kind of iterating thread that compensates for whatever DOM issue is causing this (assuming it isn't just exclusively the programming thus far). But I am not sure.

The Javascript code is below. I tried to keep it as minimal as possible but I couldn't figure out how to make it any smaller than this and still have it be clear. I omitted the html and css elements but kept them in the JSfiddle example.

```
$(function(){

var SynthCreationModule = (function(){   
context = new webkitAudioContext(); 
var orangeButton;
var applicationArea = document.getElementById("applicationArea"),
orangeButton = document.getElementById("orangeButton"),         
counterSynth = 1;
counterPitchInput = 1;
orangeButton.addEventListener("click",createSynth, false); 



function createSynth () {
  var synth = document.createElement("div"); 
  synth.className  = "synth";                         
  synth.id = "synthid" + (counterSynth++);
  applicationArea.appendChild(synth);
  var pitchInput = document.createElement('input');
  pitchInput.type = "range";
  pitchInput.className  = "pitchInputClass";
  pitchInput.id = "pitchInput" + (counterPitchInput++);
  pitchInput.min = "0";
  pitchInput.max="2000";
  synth.appendChild(pitchInput);



synth.onmousedown= function () {
   oscillator = context.createOscillator(),  
   oscillator.type = 2;  
   oscillator.frequency.value = pitchInput.value;                   
   oscillator.connect(context.destination);  
   oscillator.noteOn(0); 


};



synth.onmouseup = function ()    {  
oscillator.disconnect(); 

};


// Keydown & keyup events to launch oscillator. ( These don't work properly if you create two or more synths. Playing a key down works, but keyup only works on the last created synth. The previous created synths will continue to create additional oscillators but the keydown will not work to stop them.

var keydown = false;

$('body').keydown(function() {
    if(!keydown){
        synth.onmousedown();
        keydown = true;
    }
});

$('body').keyup(function() {
    synth.onmouseup();
    keydown = false;
});


$(synth).draggable(); 

};


}());

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually that you never explicitly declare and scope "oscillator" - so it's going into globals.  Try putting "this." in front of each occurrence of "oscillator", and it will work.

This isn't ideal code, though, because you're attaching a whole extra body event handler for each synth - your code

```
$('body').keydown(function() {
    if(!keydown){
        synth.onmousedown();
        keydown = true;
    }
});
```

is creating a whole separate function call and calling attachEventHandler on the body under the hood, with "synth" bound to the new version; it might be better to track the list of synths (even getting them back from a body.getElementsBySelector()) and calling noteOn/Off on each one.  Up to you, though.

Comment: The second part of your comment is something I will have to work at to understand how to do exactly, but thanks for throwing it out there. I veered away from "noteon/off thinking note off was broken or not working as expected, hence oscillator.disconnect